# PostgreSQL failed imports still claim hard disk space? Need to clear cache?

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, caching, storage

I have a PostgreSQL (10.0 on OS X) database with a single table for the moment. I have noticed something weird when I'm importing a csv file in that table.

When the import fails for various reasons (e.g. one extra row in the csv file or too many characters in a column for a given row), no rows are being added to the table but PostgreSQL still claims that space on my hard disk.

Now, I have a very big csv to import and it failed several time because the csv was not compliant to begin with - so I had tons of import fails that I fixed and tried to import again. What I've realized now is that my computer storage has been reduced by 30-50 GB or so because of that and my database is still empty.

- Is that normal?
- I suspect this is somewhere in my database cache. Is there a way for me to clear that cache or do I have to fully reinstall my database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting rows into the database will increase the table size.

Even if the `COPY` statement fails, the rows that have been inserted so far remain in the table, but they are *dead rows* since the transaction that inserted them failed.

In PostgreSQL, the SQL statement `VACUUM` will free that space. That typically does not shrink the table, but it makes the space available for future inserts.

Normally, this is done automatically in the background by the *autovacuum daemon*.

There are several possibilities:

- You disabled autovacuum.
- Autovacuum is not fast enough cleaning up the table, so the next load cannot reuse the space yet.

What can you do:

- Run `VACUUM (VERBOSE)` on the table to remove the dead rows manually.
- If you want to reduce the table size, run `VACUUM (FULL)` on the table. That will lock the table for the duration of the operation.

Comment: Managed to reclaim 100 Gb